# How can I rename of old files?

Tags: bash, sed, sh, rename

I have a directory like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 15:04 tmp_FILE2015_123_1_3123.LOG
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 15:04 tmp_FILE2015_133_1_3123.LOG
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 16:04 tmp_FILE2015_133_1_3125.LOG
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 16:04 tmp_FILE2015_133_1__3223125.LOG
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 16:04 tmp_FILE2015_133_1_3223125.LOG
```

I need to remove tmp_ and I can do like this:

```
for i in *; do s=$(sed -r 's/^(tmp_)(.*.LOG)/\2/' <<< $i); if [[ "$i" != "$s" ]]; then mv "$i" "$s"; fi; done;
```

But I need to do this for just older than 1 hour (modified time) files:

For example ( now: Jan 7 16:10 ):

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 13:00 FILE2015_123_1_3123.LOG
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 15:04 FILE2015_133_1_3123.LOG
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 15:01 FILE2015_133_1_3125.LOG
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 16:04 tmp_FILE2015_133_1__3223125.LOG
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 16:10 tmp_FILE2015_133_1_3223125.LOG
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will operate on all files modified in the last hour:

```
for orig_file in $(find . -type f -depth 1 -mtime -60m); do
    new_file="${orig_file#./tmp_}"
    if [[ "$new_file" != "$orig_file" ]]; then
        mv "$orig_file" "$new_file";
    fi;
done
```

If you want to operate on files older than one hour use `+60m` instead

I've changed the use of sed to use some built in bash functionality.